# MGTwitter,libxml/xmlversion.h file not found

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, libxml2

I am having an app which is running very well on my simulator and on my device also but when I try to archive  it gives me an error of libxml/xmlreader.h in MGTwitterLibXMLParser.h file.

Please give me suggetions on it....

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

set the `Header Search Path` in `TARGETS` To `usr/include/libxml2` .

Comment: I already did that and that just solved the error of debugging and running the app on simulator and device but its not archiving.Thanks....